# Split a string with html tags in it while maintaining proper html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to split a string that has html tags in it.

*Example:*

```
var html = "The Company is in the business of <mark><i><b>[institutions contained herein.<mark><i><b>Parties Agreed.</b></i></mark>";
```

If the user clicks the div after the word 'Parties', they should end up with these two variables with incomplete html:

```
"The Company is in the business of <mark><i><b>[institutions contained herein.<mark><i><b>Parties "
```

&

```
 Agreed.</b></i></mark>
```

I tried using this: `window.getSelection().anchorOffset` but that includes html tags while deducing the Offset and split doesn't return the required strings.

[Fiddle link.](https://jsfiddle.net/7y76y49u/2/)

Following is the div:

```
<div>The Company is in the business of<mark>[institutions contained herein.]</mark><i><b>Parties Agreed.</b></i></div>
```

JS:

```
var nodeText = $('div').html();

$('div').on('click', function(e) {
  var userSelection = window.getSelection(),
    start = userSelection.anchorOffset,
    nodeBefore = nodeText.substr(0, start),
    nodeAfter = nodeText.substr(start, nodeText.length);
  console.log(nodeBefore);
  console.log(nodeAfter)
});
```

The variable 'start' is not returning the accurate value when a user clicks on a 'b' or 'mark' tag and hence the 'nodeBefore' and 'nodeAfter' aren't accurate either. Click on the rendered text in the fiddle and you will see the issue.

Comment: Posting a JSFiddle sample will help.

Comment: It's grabbing the anchorOffset relative to the element you clicked; you need the anchorOffset of the parent element _to_ the click location. You'll likely need to do something along the lines of checking the length of the parent element to the node clicked, then you'll have the true 'chars' between the parent element and the click location. **EDIT:** What's the larger feature you're trying to do? Might be able to solve it another way.

Comment: @user961954: I did post a fiddle link.

Comment: @TaylorDaughtry: This is part of a document builder where users have the ability to upload a word document and then make edits after the document contents get parsed. I have the text from word in the form of 'html' variable and now I need to figure this issue out where users can separate the parsed text into separate paragraphs. But split isn't working as intended.

Comment: I don't suppose it'd be possible to do this before parsing it as HTML? It'd just be a long string before then, while being a little annoying to work with, would it make relatively simple to get the actual anchorOffset that you need.

Comment: The parser separates the paragraphs from the document and renders them as individual divs, then the users need an ability to split those individual divs to build the desired document, so splitting it before parsing won't resolve the issue here sadly. Yes, the anchorOffset is working by 'node' or something.